# Sending specific folder to HTTPS and the rest from non-www to www, while keeping the rest of the laravel routes working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I am trying to write a `.htacess` file such that:

1. The site runs php 5.4
2. Requests to domain.com run index.php first
3. Requests to `http://domain.com/checkout` are redirected to `https://domain.com/checkout`
4. All requests to domain.com are redirected to www.domain.com

So here is my attempt:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        # Use PHP 5.4
        AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php

        Options -MultiViews
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/checkout|/order)
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]

    </IfModule>
```

But when I make a post to `domain.com/cart` the user is automatically redirected to `domain.com/index.php`

Please let me know where I am going wrong...

Comment: Your first block of rewrite conditions is only checking that the requested file does not exist and is not a directory. So, unless you have a file literally named **cart** (without a file extension), it will trigger the redirect to index.php  You can add extra checks to ignore other requests like so: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^cart$`

Comment: /cart is a route - I am using laravel php framework. I work with routes mostly. I removed first block and now I get 404s for all routes

Comment: In that case, ignore what I said. But, using an MVC framework, you probably shouldn't be editing the .htaccess file for this. This should be handled in the routes.php file; either with a controller or `Route::get('/cart', function(){...})` (should work in Laravel 3, not sure about 4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you need to understand that such rules in `.htaccess` files are run on a first-come, first-serve basis. Also, you are using the `L` flag for each of them.

So, you should make sure that the two conditions and rule for silent-mapping to `index.php` should come last. Move those down to below the https and www-on rules.

Now, of course a request to `/cart` will be mapped to `index.php`; that's what it's programmed to do. However, you say "redirected"... Does that mean that it shows `index.php` in the address bar? If that is the case, the fix I've mentioned should sort that out (always check for redirects first, and then do the necessary mapping).

Like @scotsninja said in the comments, these things should be handled by Laravel itself. Your `.htaccess` file should only be used to map anything that is not a file or directory to the index file, or Laravel bootstrap.

Comment: What does the L flag mean? and why should I or should I not use it.

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked for me. What does the L flag mean? Where can I get an easy to understand tut on htaccess?

Comment: The `L` flag can be directly translated as "stop here upon match". So, if the rule matched, no further rules will be processed. It is short for `last`. I'd take a look at Perishable Press - if I'm not mistaken, they have pretty decent tutorials on Hypertext Access.